# Magento 2 disappearing elements in production

Tags: magento2

Has anyone else had issues with images and other elements disappearing from Magento 2 in production? I'm currently running Magento version 2.3.2. I've noticed time and time again that the category and product detail page (product) images keep disappearing.

I've also noticed other elements inside of the admin area disappearing as well. See image:

[image]

I also noticed that when the PDP image disappears the actual image element isn't even loaded. I've made sure my folder and file permissions are right and tried running `php -f bin/magento cache:clean` thinking it was a caching issue but to no avail.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Why the negative vote? Seems like a perfectly good question to me.

Comment: I don't know why someone gave negative on this. there is nothing wrong with this question. giving +1 on this

Comment: Thank you @ShoaibMunir!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try whit `php -f bin/magento indexer:reindex`,
but first look the status whit `php -f bin/magento ìndexer:status`

This should be the steps:

```
php -f bin/magento indexer:info  
php -f bin/magento indexer:status  
php -f bin/magento indexer:reset catalog_category_product     
php -f bin/magento indexer:reindex
php bin/magento cache:flush
php bin/magento cache:clean
```

Comment: Not sure why I didn't think to check that but running php -f bin/magento indexer:reindex fixed the issue.